# How to use gnu gcc flag -mpc32, -mpc64 and -mpc80?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, floating-point-conversion, x87

I got these GCC flags from the [GNU GCC compiler Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html). But when I tried to use those flags (`-mpc32`, `-mpc64` and `-mpc80`) I couldn't observe the behavior. So I need help on how to use these flags with a sample code.

sample code I tried: test.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    double weight = 1.0f;
    double roiSize = 137.142364501953125f;
    double thresholdValue = 5400.0f;
    double alpha = weight / (roiSize * thresholdValue * thresholdValue);
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(100)<<"alpha = "<<f<<std::endl;
    double test = pow(roiSize, 10);
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(100)<<"alpha = "<<f<<std::endl;
}
```

Compiling options:

```
g++ -mpc32 test.cpp
g++ -mpc64 test.cpp
g++ -mpc80 test.cpp
```

Comment: Updated the code i tested with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to test different x87 precisions might be to use `long double`, which on x86 targets is the 80-bit x87 type. (Except on Windows where long double = double).

Another advantage to `long double` is that you don't have to compile with `-m32` to get it to use x87 at all.  (The default for `-m64` is `-mfpmath=sse`; double and float math will be done in XMM registers, at the type width, not widened to x87 internal precision.  But `long double` will always use x87 because SSE/SSE2 can't do 80-bit).  **TL:DR: on a normal 64-bit system building with `gcc -mpc32 foo.c`, `-mpc32` won't make any difference for math on `double` variables, because it doesn't even use the legacy x87 FPU.**

BTW, this test case also depends on being compiled with the default `-O0`, otherwise constant propagation at compile time will happen.  (And that's unlikely to respect `-mpc32`.)

---

`137.142364501953125f` is a `float` constant, rounded to float before being used as an initializer for a `double`.  So your starting values are all rounded to the nearest `float`, despite being stored as `double`.  I assume the division isn't exact, though, so you would still get rounding.

---

I assume these options just set the x87 precision on startup.  MSVC's CRT start code apparently does a similar thing, defaulting to setting 64-bit precision (53-bit mantissa, like `double`, not full precision).  See Bruce Dawson's [Intermediate Floating-Point Precision](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/) article; one of a series of FP articles.  [Index in this one](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

You can look at the compiler-generate asm to see how it does FP math: using `fld` / `fmul` / `fstp` is x87 and will be affected by the x87 precision set in the x87 control word register.

`movsd` / `mulsd` is SSE2 and precision is set by the instruction; no status / control bits can override it.  (Only the rounding mode can be changed in MXCSR, and handling of subnormals.)